# What am I doing wrong in this attempt to solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

The correct solution: [image]

My attempt:

$$\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1}y\ln x \, dx\\=y\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{1}\ln x \, dx\\=y\cdot\left.\frac{1}{x}\right|_{\sqrt{y}}^{1}\\=y-\sqrt{y}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have differentiated in place of integration

Integrating by parts, $$\int\ln xdx=\ln x\int dx-\int\left(\frac{d(\ln x)}{dx}\cdot\int dx\right)dx$$

$$=x\ln x-\int\left(\frac1x\cdot x\right)dx =x\ln x-x+C$$